# Does WebEx have software equivalent to VNC server/viewer?

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, webex

We use VNC for remote support of our building automation systems and to run our applications (Java Web Start) for those systems on mobile devices and remote desktops. Our customer is improving security and will only allow WebEx or Bomgar (BeyondTrust). BeyondTrust has a "Bomgar vs VNC" PDF and I am checking pricing.  I have searched the WebEx site and chatted with a WebEx agent who had no idea what VNC is.

Does WebEx have something equivalent to VNC server/viewer? WebEx Meetings?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

WebEX does have a remote control option. It's described here:

[https://help.webex.com/en-US/article/ndtm2gp/Webex-|-Provide-or-Request-Remote-Desktop-Control](https://help.webex.com/en-US/article/ndtm2gp/Webex-%7C-Provide-or-Request-Remote-Desktop-Control)

However there's a difference. VNC  runs as a service, so a viewer can connect to the server independently. WebEX Remote Control can only be used during an active call.

Comment: Thank you.  I clicked useful but i don't have enough reputation points.

Comment: In general, if a question solves your issue, just click the swhoosh mark to accept it. You can always un-accept it, if a better one comes up. Also if you find your solution that's better than answer you've accepted, you're quite welcome to answer your own question and accept your own answer - even encouraged to, see Help files :-) Accepting marks the question to contain a solution in searches, and lifts it out of the Unaccepted queue.

Comment: And you're welcome, of course - happy to help :-)